# Close Angular Modal when I click on the X button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning **Angular** and I made a Modal in my project. If I click on the class that has the `openDialog()` function it opens the modal.

I want to be able to close that modal as well when I click on the **X**.

```
  <a class="portfolio__item" target="_blank" (click)="openDialog()">
        <img src="assets/img/mywork-img/portfolio-05.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
    </a>

<dialog id="my-dialog-pubcrawl" class="my-dialog">
   
   <div class="np-row">
    <div class="np-title">This is a dialog window</div>

    <div class="np-close-btn" title="Close">X</div> 
</div>
    
</dialog>
```

**.ts file:** This opens the modal

```
  openDialog() {
    let myDialogPubcrawl:any = <any>document.getElementById("my-dialog-pubcrawl");
    myDialogPubcrawl.showModal();
}
```

The Modal:

[image]

How can I close the modal by clicking on the X in Angular?

Comment: To really help you fix this code. We need to understand whats myDialogPubcrawl is, or how this .showModal() is doing.
But I can say that to "click outside" the modal and close it. The easy way is to have a backdrop div. Positioned behind the modal, with a dismiss() click. Same dismiss() to puth on the X button.

Comment: myDialogPubcrawl is the TS variable for the my-dialog-pubcrawl HTML id. 
ShowModal(9 displays the dialogue as a modal. See more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieveing that is to store the instance of the dialog and call the close method:

```
<a class="portfolio__item" target="_blank" (click)="openDialog()">
        <img src="assets/img/mywork-img/portfolio-05.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
    </a>

<dialog id="my-dialog-pubcrawl" class="my-dialog">
   
   <div class="np-row">
    <div class="np-title">This is a dialog window</div>

    <div class="np-close-btn" title="Close" (click)="closeDialog()">X</div> 
</div>
    
</dialog>
```

```
myDialogPubcrawl:any;

openDialog() {
    this.myDialogPubcrawl = <any>document.getElementById("my-dialog-pubcrawl");
    this.myDialogPubcrawl.showModal();
}

closeDialog() {
    this.myDialogPubcrawl.close();
}
```